# Code::Blocks: CMake generated Makefile says "Nothing to be done."

Tags: makefile, mingw, cmake, codeblocks

I just installed Code::Blocks with MinGW on my Win7 64 Box and tried to compile a CMake generated project (namely openclonk).

```
-------------- Clean: all in clonk ---------------

Cleaned "clonk - all"

-------------- Build: all in clonk ---------------

Using makefile: Makefile
Execution of 'make.exe -s -f Makefile all' in 'C:\Users\Julius\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\OpenClonk' failed.
Nothing to be done.
```

If I run

```
C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f "C:/Users/Julius/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/OpenClonk/Makefile" clonk
```

from cmd it starts to compile...

Obviously, I'd like to know how to fix compiling from C::B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code::Blocks is executing this:

```
make.exe -s -f <makefile> all
```

and you are manually executing this:

```
mingw32-make.exe -f <makefile> clonk
```

The main difference here is most likely the make target.  Re-configure Code::Blocks to make the `clonk` target instead of the default `all`.  Or, add a target that looks like `all: clonk` to the top of your makefile (assuming there isn't already an `all` target defined).

If that doesn't solve your problem, you might also want to investigate whether calling `make.exe` instead of `mingw32-make.exe` is making a difference (you can reconfigure this in your project settings).

Comment: The target made no difference, changing from make.exe to mingw32-mage.exe did the trick.