# Error when building opencv2.4.2 (with cmake 2.8.9) with codeblocks 10.05 on Win7 32-bit.

Tags: opencv, cmake, codeblocks

```
-------------- Clean: all in OpenCV ---------------

Cleaned "OpenCV - all"

-------------- Build: all in OpenCV ---------------

Using makefile: Makefile
Execution of 'make.exe -s -f Makefile all' in 'C:\opencv\build' failed.
Nothing to be done.
```

I found a threat on that issue right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809980/codeblocks-cmake-generated-makefile-says-nothing-to-be-done) in stack overflow.

However, I don´t know how and where to change from "make.exe" to "mingw32-mage.exe" !?
I followed all instructions to generate the opencv2.4.2 project with cmake but I think that the makefiles aren´t properly generated due to fact that there ist only the CmakeLists.txt file in the workspace of codeblocks

Could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

In the CMake GUI program find variable called `CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL` or `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` in case of old CMake. Change it to whatever you want and reconfigure/regenerate the cache.