# Code::blocks cmake makefile nothing to be done when building

Tags: c++, codeblocks, physfs

I've downloaded PhysFS and attempted to build it with Cmake. The option I
generated with is Code::Blocks makefiles, which generated a project file.

I supposed it was as easy as opening that project file and trying to build but
that didn't happen.

Upon building the project I get

```
-------------- Build: all in PhysicsFS ---------------

Using makefile: Makefile
Execution of 'make.exe -s -f Makefile all' in
'C:\Documents and Settings\Stefan.MONA-H6H4KPUJNF\Desktop\build' failed.
Nothing to be done.
```

I've tried checking out a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809980/codeblocks-cmake-generated-makefile-says-nothing-to-be-done), but the options in the answer
were already good, and it didn't work.

I'm on windows XP SP3

Comment: @gokcehan: Why are you editing questions just to add line breaks to the Markdown source?

Comment: @Sidnicious without the linebreak it shows up an annoying horizontal scrollbar for code alikes.

Comment: @gokcehan That’s totally reasonable, it just also looks like you’re adding a bunch of line breaks to the Markdown parts of the question, which makes it hard to see what you’re actually changing :). Take a look at the Markdown source diff of [your edit to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13073511/revisions) to see what I mean.

Comment: @Sidnicious ahh sry, that's just my external text editor. it's using hard line breaks for regular text. I should probably fix it..